# Delay notifications for a productive day

Tags: android, productivity, notification

I'm looking for an app to delay my Android notifications, and make them all pop together every X minutes.

Mobile apps try to get as much attention as possible by popping notifications right away.
Sometimes it's ok to disable those notifications, but sometimes I want to see them, once in a while.

For example, this is how I would set the app:

- Whatsapp: every 5 minutes
- Gmail: every 30 minutes
- Facebook: every 2 hours

I couldn't find any app to do that, any ideas?

Comment: Afraid you're correct that such an app cannot be found. I've setup a [list of apps for notification manipulation](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543) you might cross-check (maybe I missed that feature with one of the apps), but I cannot remember having seen that feature.

Comment: Could it be an option to get the different apps to make email notifications, and then do something with how you read emails?  Currently I don't go on Facebook either before I don't have anything else to do, or because I get read an email notification of something interesting.  Possibly such a scheme could be combined with [ifttt](https://ifttt.com/wtf) which can do stuff on your behalf...

Comment: @Izzy could you post that as an answer? I think you have compiled enough evidence to claim that "It doesn't exist, yet" is the correct answer.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I'm not sure that "I haven't found" equals "it doesn't exist". Though, a Google search on "android delayed notifications" only gives links on "how to fix delayed notifs", and "timed notifications" just links to code for scheduling them. Still checking. I can in fact think of a solution on "how to do it", but not in a way suitable to the "average user" (I think of *Tasker* here, which can react on notifications and also issue them; not sure if that would be acceptable for the OP).

Comment: If you are a domain expert in the field in question (you are) AND you have compiled a list of your findings AND its all that documented as it is, then: Yes I would say that means "It doesn't exist (yet)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>As requested by [Angelo Fuchs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/94/angelo-fuchs), I post this as an answer though it doesn't contain an app recommendation:</sup>

Having done a pretty thorough search (while updating my [list of apps for notification manipulation](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543) along) I'm pretty sure that such an app does not exist. My research not only included several major market platforms (Google, F-Droid, Aptoide), but also the [Xposed repository](http://repo.xposed.info/).

Though we usually say that "I haven't found" does not equal "it doesn't exist" (even not with the limitation of "yet"): I guess I can consider myself quite familiar with what kind of Android apps are around (with few exceptions like games or asocial networking (Facebook & Co.)) – which at least makes it highly unlikely for such an app having slipped through my nets. The closest you can get to this is setting "silent times", when *all* notifications are suppressed – or limit how often an app is permitted to notify you in a given timeframe; examples for both can be found in above linked list.

I gladly stand corrected and remove my answer if someone can prove otherwise, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if many people share my need for such app, maybe it's worth hiring someone to develop it.

Comment: Sounds like a useful thing to me, and – at least on rooted devices – I'd say not impossible to create. I have an Xposed module in mind for that, but there might also be other possibilities. I vaguely remember some forum had an area to suggest app-ideas to developers, or you could pick one from my list were it would make sense to be "added as feature", and place a feature-request. If it gets realized, make sure to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :) Good luck!